# Comparing two strings with strcmp() give EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, string, strcmp, red-black-tree, string.h

I have this function to insert a node in a red-black tree. The order key of this red-black tree is the string `id_prod` value, compared by the function `strcmp`. When I try to insert a node in this structure Xcode give to me this alert `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

this is the function:

```
void insert_id(node *sent, node *new_node)
{
    if (sent->parent == NULL)
    {
        new_node->left = new_node->right = sent;
        sent->parent = new_node;
        new_node->color_node = black;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        temp = sent->left;

        while (temp != sent)
        {
            if(strcmp(temp->id_prod, new_node->id_prod) < 0)
            {
                temp = temp->left;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp->right;
            }
        }
        if (strcmp(new_node->id_prod, temp->id_prod) < 0)
        {
            temp->left = new_node;
            new_node->parent = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->right = new_node;
            new_node->parent = temp;
        }
        new_node->left = new_node->right = sent;
        new_node->color_node = black;
        setup_tree(sent, new_node);
    }
    return;
}
```

The strings are in a file. This is the function that read and assign data from file to struct node:

struct:

```
typedef struct node
{
color   color_node;
char    id_prod[5],         
        name[20],           
        id_piece[5];        
struct  node    *left,
                *right,
                *parent;
} node;
```

Function:

```
node* get_node_file(FILE *in)
{
node *new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

fscanf(in, FORMAT_IN,   new_node->id_prod,
                        new_node->name,
                        new_node->id_piece);


new_node->left = NULL;
new_node->right = NULL;
new_node->parent = NULL;
new_node->color_node = black;
return new_node;
}
```

and this is the Main:

```
#define STORE "Magazzino.txt"

int main()
{

FILE    *input;
node *sent = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
sent->color_node = black;
sent->left = sent->right = sent->parent = NULL;


input = fopen(STORE, "r");

insert_id(sent, get_node_file(input));
insert_id(sent, get_node_file(input));
insert_id(sent, get_node_file(input));



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: The first if with the strcmp in the instruction. But I think that also the second can give the same error, but I don't know why.

Comment: Are your strings properly NULL terminated?

Comment: The most likely problem is unterminated strings.  You've not presented the code that needs to be checked for causing such a problem to arise.

Comment: You have a memory leak. First you set `temp` to the result of `malloc()`, then you immediately replace it with `temp = sent->left;`.

Comment: Do your array lengths in the structure have enough room for the trailing null bytes? `id_prod` and `id_piece` can only be 4 characters long, not 5.

Comment: I know. I've set `id_prod[5]` because i need a 4 char array. The memory leak depend on?

Comment: I like to declare string variables and members as `char name[N+1]`, where N is the max number of chars I want to reserve for the string. The `+1` makes it clear that I'm explicitly allocating space for the terminating NUL char.

Comment: loops like: `while (temp != sent)`  need to also be checking for NULL